# How to query merges including changeset change details?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm running some version control queries, and would like to look at the changes inside the returned changesets.

When I query using [QueryHistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.queryhistory.aspx), some overloads let me specify `includeChanges: true`, which means that the returned `ChangeSet`s have their `Changes` property populated, and I can look at it - great!

When I query using [QueryMergesWithDetails](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.querymergeswithdetails.aspx), I don't get to specify `includeChanges`, So the returned `ChangeSet`s have `Changes=null`, which I can't use.

I've tried:

- Getting the changes using [GetChangesForChangeset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getchangesforchangeset.aspx), but that's a round-trip to the server for each changeset, which is slow.
- Using [QueryMergesExtended](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.querymergesextended.asp), but it only produces [ExtendedMerge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.extendedmerge.aspx)s, which only has the changeset Id. This means that I'll have to query the server again for each changeset, which is slow again.

***Questions:***

1. How can I query like `QueryMergesWithDetails`, but have the changes populated?
2. Failing that, how can I query the server for changes of a batch of changesets?

Answer (score 2):

I have hit this roadblock myself.  I do not know of any way to issue a query that retrieves multiple changesets that includes both the Changes and MergeHistory for each changeset.  The best workaround that I have discovered you have already mentioned in your question:

Query changesets using `QueryHistory` with the `includeChanges=true` flag.  And then iterate through the set of changesets and call `GetChangesForChangeset` with `includeMergeSourceInfo=true`.  I have discovered that this process isn't actually that slow, but it does involve a round-trip.

If you are willing to work outside of the TFS API, you could write a custom SQL query that would pull all of the data you need in one query, but it's never really recommended to work directly against the TFS database.